# Dynamically remove substring from string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, substring

I have a somewhat straight forward dilemma but I have not been able to find a solution for it.

I am getting a JSON file from a MongoDB database and using [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to convert it into a string:

```
client = MongoClient("XXXX")
db = client.testdb
table = db.testingtable
document = table.find()
document = list(document)
docs = json.dumps(document,default=str)
print(docs)
```

**Current Output:**

```
[{"_id": "67", "userId": 167, "productID": "Reference('product_id', ObjectId('5f4523b893d7b757bcbd2d71'))"}]
```

How would I go about **dynamically** searching the entire string for the word `Reference` and if found, it should remove everything apart from the alphanumeric value within the brackets **without** doing this:

```
docs.replace("Reference('product_id', ObjectId('",'').replace("'))",'')
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[{"_id": "67", "userId": 167, "productID": "5f4523b893d7b757bcbd2d71"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df=pd.json_normalize([{"_id": "67", "userId": 167, "productID": "Reference('product_id', ObjectId('5f4523b893d7b757bcbd2d71'))"}])#convert to df


#Using regex, extract string between `ObjectId(`and  `)` and turn it back to json
df.assign(productID=df.productID.str.extract('(?<=ObjectId\()(.*?)(?=\))')).to_json(orient="records")


[{"_id":"67","userId":167,"productID":"'5f4523b893d7b757bcbd2d71'"}]
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however, I would say it's partially dynamic as it assumes that the `objectId` will always reside in the `productId` column, so if the `objectId` is in for example the `userId` column it wouldn't work